# Flutter - How to send a POST request using HTTP in Dart?

Tags: flutter, http, dart, post

I am using an API that converts HTTP to JSON and to get a response from the server I need to send a post request of HTML however i'm not sure how to do that?

This is my current implementation -

```
Future<String> test() async {
  var link =
      await http.get('https://example.com');
  var body = parse(link.body);
  return body.outerHtml;
}

Future<Album> createAlbum(String html) async {
  final http.Response response = await http.post(
    'https://www.html2json.com/api/v1',
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
    },
  
    body: html,
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to create album.');
  }
}
```

I call this is when my app starts like so,

```
@ovveride 
void initState() {
test().then((body) => createAlbum(body)); //Output returns HTTP error 301, am I doing something wrong?
super.initState();
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to DARSH SHAH, I solved this using dio (https://pub.dev/packages/dio).

```
dynamic response;

  Dio dio = Dio();
  Future<dynamic> test() async {
    dynamic link = await dio.get(
        'https://example.com');
    return link;
  }

  Future<dynamic> post(dynamic body) async {
    String _baseUrl = "https://html2json.com/api/v1";
    var options = Options(
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
      followRedirects: false,
    );

    final response = await dio.post(
      _baseUrl,
      data: body,
      options: options,
    );
    return response;
  }

FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          dynamic responseHTML = await test();
          response = await post(responseHTML.data); //This will contain the JSON response
        },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Checked the following code which worked for me.

```
Future<Album> createAlbum(String html) async {
  final http.Response response = await http.post(
    'https://www.html2json.com/api/v1',
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    },
  
    body: html,
  );
```

You need to change the Content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. This should do the trick.

Comment: Can you send me the html you want to parse?

Comment: I'm getting the same error even with google.com, can you try with that?

Comment: https://www.loom.com/share/91e6907a9ca4446fa8f5990c7e4dc57b

I have made a loom video for you. Check that out.

Comment: Can you share your entire code on github? Maybe im missing something

Comment: Sure. I have to use dio. For request handling, you can use whatever you want.